# Check if an item exist in observable collection

Tags: c#

I've an observable collection that is populated dynamically. I populate it through a list of items called `events`. There are situations where an event could be deleted from the events list, and when this happens I need to also remove it from the observable collection.

What I'm looking for is a simple and speedy way to do this. I tried the following:

```
 bool exist = events.Where(x => x.Home == obCollection[x].Home).Any();
```

but I cannot access `obCollection` through the `x` element because I need an index, and `x` is the actual item. I need to fix this to produce the correct elements, and afterwards I need to remove the remaining elements in the observable collection.

Comment: so you need to delete an item from `events` and `obCollection` and both have the same `index` in the collection ? or both have the same value for `Home` ?

Comment: events is updated automatically so already have the item deleted. I need to check if an item of events does not exist in the obCollection and remove it from obCollection

Comment: and yes, both have the same value home

Comment: Check answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry the first answer just was the other way around.

So you need to remove from `ObservableCollection` what was automatically removed from the `events` List:

```
var notFoundInEvents = obCollection.Where(x => !(events.Any(o => o.Home == x.Home))).ToList();

foreach (var toBeRemoved in notFoundInEvents)
{
    obCollection.Remove(toBeRemoved);
}
```

Comment: very nice, but this is just a check condition or it delete all items? I don't understand the == false condition at the end, could you explain a bit, thanks

Comment: @pollonz Check the edits above. Let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: ahh ok, so it the item is not found the removeAll will remove it in the obCollection, now is clear, thanks

Comment: @pollonz `events.RemoveAll(predicate)` removes from events. I think i understood your question the other way around. Please check the corrected answer now.